# How to convince a supervisor to accept me as PhD student although my master's is not in the same exact field?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have a M.Sc. in optics and I want to acquire a Ph.D. in quantum photonics. Every time I apply for some position, the supervisor refuses because "I don't have a suitable scientific background", or something like this.

How I can convince him to accept me, and this knowledge gap can be overcome by reading before joining the lab?

P.S. 1: I'm talking about being accepted at European universities.
P.S. 2: I have published two papers in my field of study.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the context of your question? In which country are you? Are you part of a PhD program already? What is the timeline to gain acceptance into a PhD lab?

Comment: I'm from Egypt and I'm asking several professors from different countries who are working on quantum photonics.

Comment: Can you determine specific skills needed in the new field that are not generally present in yours, or in your background? You may need to do some study.

Comment: Some positions required some experimental skills such as Raman spectroscopy, AFM or TEM.

Comment: I can not comment on the specific field in question, but I do know that in biology there is generally a big hurdle to consider foreign applicants. Graduate programs generally have mechanisms in place that help in the evaluation of foreign candidates, but if you are applying to individual labs this support is not given. If you are convinced the scientific background is the issue and time is available, I would try to acquire the background at your current university in additional courses and projects.

Comment: Thank you @MarioNiepel for your help.
I'd like to ask you if some skill out of my reach, can I read about it and take some online courses about it and state this fact to the professors? 
in other words, this knowledge gap can it be filled by some reading?

Comment: Is your MSc from a European university? Was it experiment-based or course based? Do you have any publications?

Comment: Again, I can not help with the specifics. This is quite far from my field of expertise. So I can only suggest that generally--if you are certain a skill gap is the issue--there must be ways available to close this gap. I would consider university classes, online courses, books, etc Ideal would be, again if time allows, to rotate in an appropriate lab or take any other intern-level position. But to hedge my bets, I would consider a plan B (in case you will be unable to close the skill gap or the skill gap is not the primary issue).

Comment: @JonCuster my MSc is from an Egyptian University, it was an experiment and course-based study. I have two published papers and two submitted.

Comment: Thank you @MarioNiepel

Comment: What's your quantum photonics-relevant background from optics? Unless you have that, I doubt that a prof will take the risk of a crossover student. If Quantum Photonics is critical for your PhD interests, you might consider taking another MSc abroad specifically on QP to close the perceived gap. There might be 1-year courses available.

Comment: Thank you @CaptainEmacs. Can I close this gap by some readings?

Comment: @MuhamedSewidan I cannot say what you know or do not know and so cannot comment on how reading would help close the gap of what you know. The critical point is that you have to *demonstrate* to your potential supervisors that you are PhD material. I am not sure how to prove it unless you have some type of evidence. Reading is a personal component of your skillset, but hard to demonstrate.

Comment: +1 to @CaptainEmacs. One way of demonstrating expertise acquired by reading is to write a strong cover letter with an in-depth explanation of your ideas for a PhD topic. That might motivate the PI to at least invite you for an interview, in which you can further demonstrate your expertise through a conversation.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful replies @CaptainEmacs lighthousekeeper.

So, Should I stick to my own research field and search for a Ph.D. related somehow to my expertise?

Comment: @MuhamedSewidan In my opinion, you should pick a topic you are interested in. I do not generally recommend picking a topic merely because it is what's the most feasible. However, if you wish to make a lateral move, you have to find a suitable "bridge". You need to prepare for the new topic, both in terms of your skills, but probably as well as your presentable study/work history.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Thank you for your help.